# show the coordinate axis form an algebraic set in $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

So by coordinate axis in $\Bbb{R}^3$ im assuming they mean the subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$:

$$A = \{(x,0,0),(0,y,0),(0,0,z): x,y,z \in \Bbb{R}\}.$$

Or should I write this as

$$\{(x,0,0):x \in \Bbb{R}\}\cup \{(0,y,0):y \in \Bbb{R}\} \cup \{(0,0,z):z \in \Bbb{R}\}$$

Ive noticed that the $x-$ axis is the zero set $V(y,z)$ and the $y-$axis is the zero set $V(x,z)$ and similarly the $z-$axis is the zero set $V(x,y)$ am I headed in the right direction? and does being inside of $V(x,y$) for instance imply $x,y=0$? Also for the zero set associated to (if thats the right terminology) $A$, do I take the union of these $V$'s that I found or? So if anyone wants to help out, is it just $V(y,z) \cup V(x,z) \cup V(x,y)$?

Comment: why would someone vote to close this???its a perfectly valid question and I have an attempt.

Comment: @JeanMarie i thought the $x$ axis was the set where $y,z=0$ i.e., $V(y,z)$?

Comment: Sorry, an error of mine : the $x$ axis is defined by $y^2+z^2=0$.

Comment: which occurs only when theyre both zero cause they cant be negative @JeanMarie

Comment: $(x^2 + y^2) (x^2 + z^2) (y^2 + z^2) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on what an algebraic set means for you. However, the idea is that the union of the three axes is a union of $3$ "irreducible" algebraic sets. A peculiarity of real numbers (as compared with the complex numbers) is that the $x$-axis can be written as $V(y^2+z^2)$: indeed, $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ satisfies $y^2+z^2=0$ if and only if $y_0=z_0=0$. An analogous argument gives the $y$-axis as $V(x^2+z^2)$ and the $z$-axis as $V(x^2+y^2)$.

If you have a set defined by the equation: $V(P)$ and another defined by $V(Q)$, note that $V(P) \cup V(Q) = \{(x,y,z): P(x,y,z) = 0\:\text{or}\:Q(x,y,z) = 0\}= \{(x,y,z):P(x,y,z)Q(x,y,z)=0\}$.

This says that taking the product of polynomials on the algebraic side corresponds to taking the union of the zero loci geometrically. This tells you that the condition you are after is (as suggested in the comments) given by taking the product of the defining equations for each axis: $V((x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(x^2+z^2))$.

Comment: so can the $x-$axis be written as $V(y,z)$?

Comment: how do you get that its equal to $V(y^2+z^2)$

Comment: Suppose $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in \Bbb{R}^3$ is such that $y_0^2+z_0^2 = 0$. Then it follows that $y_0 = z_0 = 0$.

Comment: Though indeed, the $x$-axis can be written as $V(y,z)$ just as well. In my opinion this is a more direct route to see it as an algebraic set: simply the union of these three sets. The union of algebraic sets is algebraic, although it depends on if you have proven this or not. The proof is along the lines of what I wrote down using this argument with products.

Comment: So I could think of the algebraic set associated to the coordinate axis as $V(y,z) \cup V(x,z) \cup V(x,y)$?

Comment: i got a hint saying the ideal of the union is the intersection of the ideals in order to vanish on all axis you have to lie in the ideal of each one, is this a different way about proving it or the same thing?

Comment: Indeed, working over $\Bbb R$, the union of $f=0$ and $g=0$ is given by $f^2+g^2=0$. This won't work over $\Bbb C$ or any other unordered field.

Comment: @TedShifrin always comes in with the most highbrow comments :)

Comment: @TedShifrin is the algebraic set just $V(y,z) \cup V(x,z) \cup V(x,y)$? And how is this just $V((x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)(y^2+z^2))$

Comment: This wasn’t highbrow at all. Alekos answered your questions already. In general, remember that $fg=0$ is the union of $f=0$ and $g=0$. Why?

Comment: but how do you go from just knowing $V(x,y)$ to $x,y=0$ iff $x^2+y^2=0$ @TedShifrin is that just a clever observation to be made?

Comment: In an ordered field, $a^2\ge 0$, with equality iff $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which works over $\mathbb{R}$, or any other field too, is the following
\begin{align*}
    V&=V(x,y)\cup V(x,z)\cup V(y,z)\\
    &=V(x^2y,xy^2,y^2z,x^2z,xz^2,yz^2,xyz)
\end{align*}
Where I use $V(I)\cup V(J)=V(IJ)$ where the product $IJ$ of ideals is the set of polynomials $\sum_if_ig_i$ for $f_i\in I$ and $g_i\in J$. If your ideals are $I=(f_1,...,f_n)$ and $J=(g_1,...,g_m)$ then $IJ=(f_1g_1,f_1g_2,...,f_ng_m)$.

Comment: how did you go from the top line to the second line? I thought $V(x,y) \cup V(x,z)=x^2+xz+yx+zy$? Thats where i get confused but this is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: $V(x,y)\cup V(x,z)=V(x^2,xy,xz,yz)$

Comment: It would be better to write $V(x,y)\cup V(x,z)$ as $V$ of $(x,y)\cap (x,z)=(x,yz)$. Applying this to the whole problem, one finds the coordinate axes are $V(xy,xz,yz)$ and this ideal is the smallest possible ideal with that vanishing set.

Comment: how do you recognize that what he wrote as his answer is $V(xy,xz,yz)$? @KReiser

Comment: @MyMathYourMath $V(I)=V(\sqrt{I})$ as sets (this is the nullstellensatz), and $\sqrt{(x^2y,xy^2,y^2z,x^2z,xz^2,yz^2,xyz)}=(xy,xz,yz)$.